# Java ArrayList<String> using for loop and overwriting itself

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to make my t String save to an ArrayList. but every time I run my program more than once it overwrites the previous data I want it to be a continuation. Creating the Array inside or out of the loop doesn't seem to help it just keeps rewriting over what is already there.

```
private void sets(ArrayList<Integer> save, int answer) {
    String s = ", ";
    String t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
        t = t + String.valueOf(save.get(i)) + s;

    }
    for(int n = place ;n<1 ;){
        ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
        message.add(t);
        place=place+1;
        System.out.println(message);
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're creating a local instance of `ArrayList` within the context of the `for-loop`.  Once the `for-loop`  (and the methd) exists, the context is lost along with the reference to the `ArrayList`

Comment: Your ArrayList declaration should come before the for() loop.

Comment: In addition to the comments above - your `return` statement should be after the loop, not inside it.

Comment: @TDG Although that'd be a bit unnecesary

Comment: I'm passing to this method twice and it keeps clearing out what i previously had, Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: A gloabal arraylist and I am still left with the same problem,

Comment: @TDG This would introduce an infinite loop.

Comment: You need your t variable to either be global or a member of the class where this method resides. Additionally, since you want to save each iteration of it, you then would need to create a collection and update it each time you call the sets() method. So in other words, make a member List variable of Strings and do a tList.add(t); when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Move `ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();` to right after your class statement. Example:

```
public class xxxxx{
    ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
    //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two ways..

1. You can place the data structure at the beginning of the method **sets** and this obviously will have all the data in ***message*** lost once the method has exited.

   ```
    private void sets(ArrayList<Integer> save, int answer) {
        ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s = ", ";
        String t = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
            t = t + String.valueOf(save.get(i)) + s;
        }
       for (int n = place; n < 1;) {
           message.add(t);
           place = place + 1;
           System.out.println(message);
       }
        return;
   }
   ```
2. Or you can declare a global variable that can always handle your data for as long as the program still executes.

   ```
   private ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();

   private void sets(ArrayList<Integer> save, int answer) {
       String s = ", ";
       String t = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
           t = t + String.valueOf(save.get(i)) + s;
       }
       for (int n = place; n < 1;) {
           message.add(t);
           place = place + 1;
           System.out.println(message);
       }
       return;
   }
   ```

It all comes down to your requirements. #GOODLUCK